# Console.debug not working in ie10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I am  using Console.debug() for debugging purpose but it is not working in ie 10. I am getting  error object does not support property or method debug.

IE 10 is supporting Console.log but why it is not supporting debug method.

Comment: What does `console.debug` do different than `console.log`? I checked this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) and they say it's just an alias

Comment: IE11 does support it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265066(v=vs.85).aspx and it seems to be an alias of console.log. So you're not missing anything.

Comment: I have unexpected behavior with console.debug in IE11 - it work only if the debug console panel is opened.

Answer (score 0):

console is a object, which don´t work in a emulation lower 10.
You can solve the problem by avoid emulation mode lower 10 or replaced console with alert().